# R markdown table

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, kableextra

I am working on a paper in R Markdown. I'd like to create a table which contain math symbols. Below, it my simple code with a table:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r  echo=FALSE}
library(knitr); library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(A=c("Hello!", 100, "$x^2+100$"), L=c(10, "World!", "100+250*1"))
knitr::kable(df, escape = FALSE, booktabs = TRUE,
          caption = "An example[note]", 
          col.names = c("Left", "Right")) %>%
 add_indent(c(2, 3), level_of_indent = 1.5, all_cols = TRUE) %>%
 add_footnote(c("Source: Book."), notation = "symbol")

```
````

As a result, every time I knit the file the same error appears:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate
```

I will appreciate if very much if you help me to fix this error.

Comment: p.s. you will get much more responses if you are more specific in your title. i.e. Error: How to create a table with math symbols in R Markdown

Answer (score 0):

when I run your example it knits perfectly fine. this is what it looked like in HTML. I haven't seen that error before so I am not sure what the problem is. Perhaps it is a problem with your YAML header, or a line of code previous to the table that is causing problems. Hopefully someone else knows!

[image: Your code produced this table]